# ref or div to excel using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div, with a table inside a column of the first table. I tried to export to excel with libraries like "react-html-table-to-excel-3" but it only exported the first table and not the table that is inside the .
It's a React project, and I'm open to using any library, whether it's from npm or something typical of javascript or jquery.

```
    <div id="dvData">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Column One</th>
                <th>Column Two</th>
                <th>Column Three</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row1 Col1</td>
                <td>row1 Col2</td>
                <td>
    <table>
    <tr>
<td>row 1.1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data 1</td>
</tr>
</table>
    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row2 Col1</td>
                <td>row2 Col2</td>
                <td>row2 Col3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row3 Col1</td>
                <td>row3 Col2</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "SheetJS" library, which is a JavaScript library for reading and writing Excel files.

Visit sheetjs https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

Sample use
Before npm or yarn using install

```
npm i xlsx
```

or

```
import * as XLSX from 'https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.2/package/xlsx.mjs';
```

Export nested table data  to excel file

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx';

const exportToExcel = () => {
  const table = document.querySelector('#dvData table');

  const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([]);

  const rows = table.rows;
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const cells = rows[i].cells;
    const rowData = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
      const cell = cells[j];

      // attention here
      const nestedTable = cell.querySelector('table');
      if (nestedTable) {
        const nestedRows = nestedTable.rows;
        for (let k = 0; k < nestedRows.length; k++) {
          const nestedCells = nestedRows[k].cells;
          const nestedRowData = [];
          for (let l = 0; l < nestedCells.length; l++) {
            const nestedCell = nestedCells[l];
            nestedRowData.push(nestedCell.innerText);
          }
          rowData.push(...nestedRowData);
        }
      } else {
        rowData.push(cell.innerText);
      }
    }
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [rowData], { origin: -1 });
  }

  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Sheet1');
  const excelFile = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });

  const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
  downloadLink.href = `data:application/octet-stream;base64,${btoa(excelFile)}`;
  downloadLink.download = 'data.xlsx';
  downloadLink.click();
};
```

Comment: The same thing happens, only the first <table> appears in excel but not the <table> embedded in the <td>

Comment: Ok i will update my answer as you will find the embedded table

Comment: Koray, could you?